# Regex delete lines after match

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match domain example.com and I would like to delete all IPs beneath it

Input:

```
[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
```

Desired output:

```
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
\[example.com\](\s+^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$)*
```

It works, but not sure if thats efficient.

I'm doing my regex testing with rubular here is a sample

http://rubular.com/r/cavVHWPvT2

Comment: this doesn't seem like the job for a regex, what do you mean delete?

Comment: Well I would like to target these entries for deletion

Comment: Why don't you: `try to put the second part into an array. Then, looping it and checking for containing in the first part. If matching, delete it`?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with a complex regex, I'd do it using Ruby's [`slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
data = '[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
'

data.lines.slice_before(/\A\[/).select { |ary| ary.first[/example\.net/] }.join
# => "[example.net]\n10.100.251.22\n10.100.251.33\n"
```

Breaking it down:

```
data
  .lines # => ["[example.com]\n", "10.100.251.1\n", "10.100.251.2\n", "10.100.251.3\n", "[example.net]\n", "10.100.251.22\n", "10.100.251.33\n"]
  .slice_before(/\A\[/) # => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f987b8b4528>:each>
  .select { |ary| ary.first[/example\.net/] } # => [["[example.net]\n", "10.100.251.22\n", "10.100.251.33\n"]]
  .join # => "[example.net]\n10.100.251.22\n10.100.251.33\n"
```

Regular expressions are great, and I use them when necessary but they're not always the best tool for a task. They can be very fragile and very treacherous, and greatly increase the task of maintaining code, especially as they get more complex.

This could also be accomplished using a flip-flop but explaining that is left to a different question: "[What is a flip-flop operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456634/what-is-a-flip-flop-operator)".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Find:**

```
\[example\.com\].*?(\[(?:(?!example\.com).)*?\])
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

## Regex101

Comment: First of all, update your question with the tool you are using.  My regex would work in a tool such as Notepad++, but perhaps not yours.

Comment: `.*` means match any character, zero or more times.  `.*?` means match any character zero or more times, but it is a non greedy match.

Comment: Explore this regex using the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

We are given

```
str =<<-END
[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
END
  #=> "[example.com]\n10.100.251.1\n10.100.251.2\n10.100.251.3\n[example.net]\n10.100..."
```

The question is a bit confusing in that the desired output is said to be

```
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
```

but that is also what is to be deleted. What follows returns the lines that are not deleted, but it would be a simple matter to change it to return the deleted bits. Also, the question doesn't make clear if the string `"[example.net]"` is known or if it's just an example of what might follow the `"[example.com]"` "block". Nor is it clear if there are exactly two "blocks", as in the example, or there could be one or more than two blocks.

If you know `"[example.net]"` immediately follows the `"[example.com]"` block, you could write

```
r = /
    \[example\.com\]     # match string
    .*?                  # match any number of characters, lazily
    (?=\[example\.net\]) # match string in positive lookahead
    /mx                  # multiline and free-spacing modes

puts str[r]
[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
```

If you don't know what follows the `"[example.com]"` "block", except that that the first line of the following block, if there is one, contains at least one character other than a digit or period, you could write

```
r = /
    \[example\.com\]\n  # match string
    .*?                 # match any number of any characters, lazily
    (?:[\d.]*\n)        # match a string containing > 0 digits and periods,
                        # followed by a newline, in a non-capture group
    +                   # match the above non-capture group > 0 times
    /x                  # free-spacing mode

puts str[r]
[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
```

Comment: Nice regex...looks like mine ;-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, there certainly are similarities, but differences too, as I'm returning the keepers and you're returning the removals.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland and Tim, I'm having truble running the example in my temrinal, you think you can help me with a sample on http://rubular.com ? Thanks

Comment: Sure, Dean, but for me it will have to wait until morning.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, I am returning the keepers.  Try it in Notepad++ and you will see.

Comment: @Tim, then why the capture group followed by `$1` for the non-keepers? Ah, because you interpreted those to be the keepers. Whose interpretation of the question is correct? I have no idea. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is very close. What you miss is a bit of grouping and a linebreak construct at the right place:

```
/^\[example\.com\]\R*(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\R*)*/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/zEOZ3oO2MF)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `\[example\.com\]` - `[example.com]` literal substring
- `\R*`  - zero or more linebreaks (for older Ruby versions, use `(?:\r?\n|\r)*`)
- `(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\R*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}`  - 3 sequences of 1 to 3 digits and a dot
  - `\d{1,3}`  - 1 to 3 digits
  - `\R*`  - 0+ linebreaks

And a [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/pA1qkY):

```
str =<<DATA
[example.com]
10.100.251.1
10.100.251.2
10.100.251.3
[example.net]
10.100.251.22
10.100.251.33
DATA
rx = /^\[example\.com\]\R*(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\R*)*/
puts str[rx]
```

Comment: We end up with almost same regular expressions, but I still think `\s*` is better, than `\R*`. Either one claims the explicit precise format, then there should not be `*` matchers, or let’s allow spaces after IPs :)

Comment: `\s` matches horizontal whitespace, so `[example.com]78.78.89.67556.87.87.87` can also be matched. I understand they must be on the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0):

### Treat Your Data Like an INI File: Scan for Sections

One way to deal with your data is to treat it like an INI file. A regex with the [multi-line option](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) enabled can break a string representation of your INI file into an array of sections as follows:

```rb
ini = <<~'EOF'
  [example.com]
  10.100.251.1
  10.100.251.2
  10.100.251.3
  [example.net]
  10.100.251.22
  10.100.251.33
EOF

# Scan for INI section headers.
sections = ini.scan /^\[.*?\]$[^\[]*/m
```

You can then extract just the sections you want using [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). For example, to extract the `example.net` section:

```rb
section_title = 'example.net'
sections.grep /\A\[#{Regexp.escape section_title}\]\s*$/
#=> ["[example.net]\n10.100.251.22\n10.100.251.33\n"]
```

### Caveats

1. The multi-line regex above assumes you have the entire file loaded as a single String object. If you're doing something else, you may need a different approach.
2. Note the importance of [Regexp#escape](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape), which ensures that your string is properly converted for use in a regex pattern. Otherwise, characters like `[`, `.`, and `]` would not match as you might expect.
3. INI files can be more complex than your sample data. You might consider a writing a real INI parser, or using a gem like [inifile](https://rubygems.org/gems/inifile), rather than trying to handle all the possible edge cases in one regular expression.